# Custom UIButton with Image and Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I want to create custom UIButton like

[
       IMAGE here

text here

]

How can I do it?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: So far as I know, it isn't possible to combine images and text in a button without using just one big image with the text already in it... possibly artfully positioning a UILabel...

Comment: The label/text for the button will be populated at runtime, any idea how it can be achieved? Is there any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you might do it:

Define a button, image view, and a label in IB and drag and resize the button to it's full size.  Then, position the image view and label 'inside' the button.  Set the image and the text and then set their userInteractionEnabled properties to NO, so that all touches are passed to the underlying button.  Voila.

Comment: No problem.  When stuck, use www.cocoacontrols.com, because somebody's probably already done the work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Set the background image on the button.  Set the text.  Adjust the text inset as necessary.